What is permitted to look and touch and what is not permitted while purchasing slave
From the Athar below:
أنَّ ابنَ عمرَ كان يضعُ يدَهُ بيْنَ ثَديَيها ( يعنى الجاريةَ ) وعلى عُجُزِها من فوقِ الثيابِ ويكَشفُ عن ساقِها
It tells that ibn Umar[ra] used to check the slavegirls in public in market. What is limit prescribed by scholars to check a slave before purchasing, meaning what it is permissible to see and touch as well as what is prohibited to see and touch

Logically I don't think you can touch them I mean that sounds weird they are not ur maharraam or anything nor do u own them yet so I don't think you can. Plus you can't go and touch one first you have to establish a relationship with them prior ( thats werid). I'm a layman so yh not a scholar. Visually makes logical sense but yh. All you need to know that regardless of the answer islam is perfect. I wouldn't personally focus on such minor things plus slavery is abolished.

I am really shocked when I saw a lot of questions about slaves in this site !

Most people on this site that are gonna answer you question are laymen if u want a scholar then go on islamqa and ask it. Furthermore, u should be asking more relevant question on how to treat people in islam since ur response was immature. I mean I understand the first part fine but calling it bigoted liberal etc is out of bound. Learn to respect ur fellow brothers and sisters in islam.
